# How can I attach an API Key as a token barer to a POST method with terraform aws api gateway resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authentication, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have dissected the Terraform AWS Api Gateway Resources documentation and I don't find a clear documentation around how I can create and attach an API Key as a Token Barer autorization to an API Gateway POST method with terraform

My CURL command would look something like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://foobar123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer AAABBBsKen4vcVDQVkZyu7lpEWGcs1o64bz7TCb1' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{"foo": "bar"}'
```

How do I achieve this with terraform?

Comment: I can create a key: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_api_key.html
I just don't know how to associate/attach it with the API Gateway POST method

Comment: I don't know terraform much myself, but as far as I understand TF is for provisioning only right. Once you have your API setup in API Gateway and your API key, you just have to use CURL or Postman to test the API. And you are already doing that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It's an option on the gateway method (the last option):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "task_method" {
  rest_api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id      = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_task.id
  http_method      = "POST"
  authorization    = "NONE"
  api_key_required = true
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_method.html#api_key_required) isn't very explicit, but this example does work.